# How to add custom view helpers to Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-framework2

I have earlier asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062923/how-to-add-custom-view-helpers-to-zend-framework-2) question, and I got good answers there.
However, that was for beta4, and no longer works.

So where and how do I add my own view helpers to ZF2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should add them to your `module.config.php` under `view_helpers` like this:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'ModuleName' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),

'view_helpers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'showmessages' => function($sm) {
            $helper = new ModuleName\Helper\MessageShower();
            // do stuff with $sm or the $helper
            return $helper;           
        },
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
        'selectmenu' => 'ModuleName\Helper\SelectMenu',   
        'prettyurl'  => 'ModuleName\Helper\PrettyUrl',
    ),  
),
```

Here I show two ways of creating the helpers. If all they need to do is to be instantiated, just add their name (including namespace) as `invokables`. If you need to do stuff with them or the `ServiceManager`, create them through the `factories` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The beta5 had a BC regarding the servicemanager. This applies for the view helper manager as well. Have a look [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/1695) - there's even an example for view helpers a bit down too.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the BC break, but couldn't find out how to add helpers. This was what I needed to make it work. Will probably post a working example as an answer for others to see.