# Zend Framework 2: Zend_Navigation

Tags: zend-framework2

I am just wondering what would be the best way, to use Zend_Navigation in Zend Framework2. At the moment i am trying to a add a Config for a Header and a Footer Menu. Both Menus should be populated automatically. Though, i have run into a lot of Problems:

a) The best place for the Default Menu should be hopefully the Application-Module

b) I added the following to the root of module.config.php:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'helper_map' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Application\View\Helper\Navigation'
    ),
),
```

My Navigation.php is located in ./module/Application/src/Application/View/Helper/Navigation.php

and contains:

```
class Navigation extends AbstractContainer {
    public function __construct($menu = null) {
        var_dump($menu);
    }
}
```

I know that the Class may be wrong. But at the Moment i did not get ZF2 to even load the Class. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using beta5 - you're just configuring your viewhelper wrong. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392624/how-to-add-custom-view-helpers-to-zend-framework-2-beta5) on how to do it correctly.

On how to use navigation: I'd create a service in the servicemanager called `navigation` and put my navigation into a new config-key:

```
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        // your navigation config goes here
    ),
    'servicemanager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => function($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('Configuration');
                $navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation($config->get('navigation'));
                return $navigation;
            }
        ),
    ),
    'view_helpers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => function($sm) {
                return new \My\View\Helper\Navigation($sm->get('navigation'));
            }
        ),
    ),
);
```

(Not sure about the navigation class names. Haven't had a look on them.)

This does three things:

- Provide a service called `navigation` pointing to the actual instance
  if zend's navigation
- Provide your view helper and hand it a reference to the instance of your navigation
- Create a new top-level key `navigation` containing the navigation configuration. Other modules can add custom navigation here without changing anything in your setup.

For example in your controllers you code fetch the navigation instance by calling

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('navigation');
```

while in your view helper has access to the navigation by it's constructor:

```
Navigation extends // ...
{
    public function __construct($navigation)
    {
        // do anything you want
    }
}
```

Other modules can add entries to your navigation by writing into the same key:

```
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        // further navigation entries
    ),
);
```

Where you put the initial logic (e.g. setting up the services/view helpers) is up to you. I prefer writing a own module for this which can be disabled with a single line of code (resulting in the navigation not being present anymore). But the default module is probably a good place as well.
Ultimately you could create your own factory-classes for the navigation and view helper instead of mixing the configuration with your code.

Disclaimer: Code's just a draft - not tested.