# zf2 navigation - 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for navigation'

Tags: zend-framework2

Hy everybody!

I am learning zf2, and trying to set up a navigation panel(based on: [Zend Framework 2: Zend_Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397226/zend-framework-2-zend-navigation)), but the answer from the computer is still:

An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
File:
/var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:453
Message:
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for navigation

The module.config.php contain:

```
   'servicemanager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => function($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('Config');
                $navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation($config->get('navigation'));
                return $navigation;
            }
        ),
    ),
```

I have an application.global.php in the main config/autoload folder which is looks like:

```
<?php

return array(
    // All navigation-related configuration is collected in the 'navigation' key
    'navigation' => array(
        // The DefaultNavigationFactory we configured in (1) uses 'default' as the sitemap key
        'default' => array(
            // And finally, here is where we define our page hierarchy
            'Album' => array(            
                    'label'      => 'Albumlista',
                    'route'      => 'album',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'pages'      => array(
                        array(
                            'label'      => 'Add',
                            'route'      => 'album',
                            'action'     => 'add'
                            )           
                       )
               ),
            'Application' => array(            
                    'label'      => 'Alap alkalmazás',
                    'route'      => 'application',
                    'action' => 'index',

               )
        ),
    ),

);
```

And from the controller i give this command:

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('navigation');
```

Could somebody help me to solve this problem?
I read about http://adam.lundrigan.ca/2012/07/quick-and-dirty-zf2-zend-navigation/ , I tried it, and I did it, but I would like to combine with acl so that I wrote this question.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the contructor for the Naviagtion class it required either an array of Pages or a Traversable object. You are passing in an array with an array of pages inside, try this:

```
'servicemanager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'navigation' => function($sm) {
            $navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;
            $navigation = $navigation->createService($sm);

            return $navigation;
        }
    ),
),
```

The default factory will automatically find your config by looking for the default node under your navigation config.

You could alternatively keep it the way you have, but pass in the "default" node (under the Navigation node in the config) to the Navigation contructor as this is the actual page definition.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved when I changed the following line in `application.config.php`

```
'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php', //[This is default setting]

config_glob_paths' => array( '<PUT_ABSOLUTE_PATH_HERE>{,*.}{global,local}.php', ),
```

in place of `'config/autoload'` full path instead of the relative path.

Comment: can you explain what your insert put_absolute_path_here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using view helper

$this->escape($this->somevar); //this is zf1 view helper

in zf2 you can escape using the view helper

$this->escapeHtml($this->somevar);