# Unable to register a view helper in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add custom view helpers to Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392624/how-to-add-custom-view-helpers-to-zend-framework-2)

I keep getting `ServiceNotFoundException`s when attempting to load a view helper in ZF2. My module configuration is as follows:

```
'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => [
        'stock' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
    ],
    'invokables' => [
        'navlink' => 'Application\View\Helper\NavLinkHelper'
    ]
]
```

The class doesn't seem to be added to the plugin registry. I've found several different methods posted over the past 6 months, none of which work. Apparently the official documentation (suggesting use of `helper_map`) is also out-of-date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `module.config.php` to include the following array. Please notice the difference of the array_key used to declare the helper-mapping.

```
return array(
    'view_helpers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'navlink' => 'Application\View\Helper\NavLinkHelper'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: How odd! Is that in your module.config.php or a global config?

Comment: `module.config.php` - notice, my array key is `view_helpers`, yours is `view_manager`

Comment: Just noticed that myself - and it works! If you amend your answer I'll mark that as the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No probs, made slight edits, guess that's what you've been asking for