# custom view helper error in zend framework 2

Tags: view, helper, zend-framework2, custom-view

I cannot seem to register a custom view helper in zend Framework 2.02 I tried all solutions posted here and anything I can think I should do but I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'ModuleName\view\Helper\mylinkhelper' not found in C:\wamp\vhosts\projectName\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 177

And here's how my module.config.php looks like:

```
return array{
      'controllers'=>array(

           ....
       ),
      'view_manager' => array(
          'template_path_stack' => array(
             'ModuleName' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
           ),    
   ),
   'view_helpers' => array(  
            'invokables' => array(  
                 'mylink' => 'ModuleName\view\Helper\mylinkhelper',   
             ),  
       ),
};
```

in my view file, I have:

```
echo $this->mylink($someparameter);
```

I appreciate any feedback on this. I don't really know what else to do here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add custom view helpers to Zend Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392624/how-to-add-custom-view-helpers-to-zend-framework-2)

Comment: It's one of the approaches I tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// ./module/Application/src/Application/View/Helper/AbsoluteUrl.php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class AbsoluteUrl extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->request->getUri()->normalize();
    }
}
```

You’ll notice that this particular helper has a dependency — a Zend\Http\Request object. To inject this, we’ll need to set up a factory with the initialization logic for our view helper:

```
    <?php
    // ./module/Application/Module.php
    namespace Application;

    use Application\View\Helper\AbsoluteUrl;

    class Module
    {
        public function getViewHelperConfig()
        {
            return array(
                'factories' => array(
                    // the array key here is the name you will call the view helper by in your view scripts
                    'absoluteUrl' => function($sm) {
                        $locator = $sm->getServiceLocator(); // $sm is the view helper manager, so we need to fetch the main service manager
                        return new AbsoluteUrl($locator->get('Request'));
                    },
                ),
            );
        }


     // If copy/pasting this example, you'll also need the getAutoloaderConfig() method; I've omitted it for the sake of brevity.
}
```

That’s it! Now you can call your helper in your view scripts:

The full URL to the current page is: `<?php echo $this->absoluteUrl(); ?>`

thanks to evan to create this [tutorial](http://blog.evan.pro/creating-a-simple-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I have yet to try this solution but it does look good. I'll get back to you with the outcome soon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the View Helper is correctly added to the `ServiceManager` since invoking `mylink()` is trying to create `ModuleName\view\Helper\mylinkhelper`.

I'd make sure the class is creatable with `new College\view\Helper\mylinkhelper();` from a controller, this is likely to throw up some clues. Also check the filename and classname are correct.

Comment: Thanks DrBeza. I'm gonna explore this option now since I can't think of any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, but there might be two things which cause you this trouble:

1. You talk about a top level namespace `ModuleName`, but in your example configuration you have the top level namespace `College`. When you have a `ModuleName` namespace and you try to load `College`, that obviously does not work
2. Your view helper cannot be autoloaded. Are you sure the class name is correct (`MyLinkHelper`), the namespace is correct (`College\View\Helper`, see also above) and the  file name is correct (`MyLinkHelper.php`). And have you enabled class-name autoloading for this module in your module class?

A third option might be the lower case "view" and "mylinkhelper" as usually you would write `College\View\Helper\MyLinkHelper` with a capital V, M, L and H. But since you are on Windows that should not matter afaik. I know for Linux you must be aware of case sensitiveness of class names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jurian! I meant ModuleName instead of College. so point 1 isn't the problem. class name is correct, namespace is correct, and the file name is correct as well. when you say "have you enabled class-name autoloding for this module in your module class?" I assume you mean register the module or tell the ModuleManager about the module then I did that.  About the capital and lower cases, I checked that as well and it doesn't seem to be the problem. Please, if you have any other thought, just let me know.

Comment: The autloader means that you do not have to `require 'My/File/Name.php'` in your code, but if you do `new My\File\Name` your class gets loaded automatically. You can check this for example by using @DrBeza his method: in some code that gets run (a controller for example) you do `$test = new College\View\Helper\MyLinkHelper` to check if autoloading of the class works. If that doesn't: there is your problem. If it does: the problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the **class file is not being loaded**. Its supposed to be included in autoload_classmap.php.

```
<?php
return array(
    '{module}\View\Helper\{helper}' => __DIR__ . '\View\Helper\{helper}.php',
);
?>
```

I ran in the same issue and this page helped me.

As I'm new to ZF, i don't know if there is another way to add the paths in autoload_classmap, i think probably there is, but i just edited the file manually.

Answer (score -1):

Got the same problem, found out by myself that view helper file was not included. while putting it into controller for testing it worked

e.g.: `require_once('module/Pages/view/Helper/RenderNav.php');`

why it has not been autoloaded ?